# MySQL Giving Wrong Query Result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following table, name "categories" in MySQl 5.5.50, running in Ubuntu 14.04.
The first lines are column names.

```
id, category_id, local_code,category
'1', 'cat1', 'lcl1', 'general 1'
'2', 'cat1', 'lcl1', 'general 2'
'3', 'cat2', 'lcl2', 'general 3'
'4', 'cat3', 'lcl3', 'general 4'
```

I then have the following simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
in category_code varchar(20))
BEGIN

    declare catcode varchar(20);
    set catcode = category_code;

    select count(id) as dummy
    from categories 
    where category_code = catcode;

END
```

When I run it thus; call test('cat1"'); I get 
dummy
4

But I expect to get 0 for 'dummy' as that "category_code" does not exist in the table.
When I run it with a "category_code" that exists I get the same wrong result

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you use the same name "category_code" as argument as well as the column name. Maybe you could try changing this into some other name like categ_code?

Comment: Thanks, Kumar. That seems to have been the problem. It is interesting, though, because I was only passing it as parameter. I did not use it the query itself! Anyways, it is working, @krishnakumar

Comment: Great.. Let me post the comment as answer then...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you use the same name "category_code" as argument as well as the column name. Maybe you could try changing this into some other name like categ_code?